# What is LED backlit display?

Tags: laptop, lcd

A laptop vendor told me that some laptops have led-backlit display which is superior to normal display. What exactly is the difference? Is it better to opt for backlit display?
Is it better for the eyes?

Answer (score 8):

This Wikipedia article is a good reference for [Backlights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlight).

[**The advantages of LED backlighting in Flatpanel Displays**](http://www.glgroup.com/News/The-advantages-of-LED-backlighting-in-Flatpanel-Displays-29702.html)

> What does LEDs have over any other backlighting source? The three most important concerns any Notebook designer has to resolve are **power**, **even lighting**, and **weight**. LEDs beat all other solutions hands down.
>
> - Power equals heat and power reduces battery life time between charges.
>     LEDs are a cool light source, the lamination to heat ratio is even better that that of fluorescent lighting. As a result LEDs provide more light per watt.
> - LEDs are chips. They are small and can be placed in a matrix pattern behind the panel to deliver an even uniform field of light across the entire viewing surface of the panel. Other sources like bulbs and tubes will generate hot spots (where the light is brighter) and producing an even field of light to the panel can be tricky and costly.
> - Once again, LEDs are chips. Small and light weight. LEDs are the winners today and will remain so for some time to come.

[**LED backlight will apply additional pressure on OLED TV and Plasma TV**](http://www.glgroup.com/News/LED-backlight-will-apply-additional-pressure-on-OLED-TV-and-Plasma-TV-41586.html)

The next step is thin-displays with [Edge-LEDs](http://www.sony.com.au/article/306397/product/kdl-40zx1) ([2](http://asia.cnet.com/reviews/home_av/tvs/0,39037594,62053016,00.htm)).

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have a backlight on almost all LCD displays. Most displays these days are LED backlit (the other big choice is cold cathode fluorescent lamps).

In general I recommend you NOT worry about the display technology, but rather, focus on whether the display looks good to you. There's plenty of good and plenty of bad displays out there, and you need to find one that works, not one that has the right buzzwords.

Think of how you are going to use the system, and look for something that will work well in your target environment.

Answer (score 1):

an LED backlit display is a display that uses LEDs to illuminate the display so it can be seen.  If you have ever seen the back light go off on a cell phone and then noticed the image remain then you know what I am talking about.  The LED is a good source of light as long as it is used with an opaque diffuser to eliminate noticeable differences in intensity.

The display itself produces color and light separately in most cases.  The color is produced on one layer and the back lighting is produced on another.